# Menú oculta elementos llamados por URL en la misma página

Tags: html, css, wordpress

En una web hecha en Wordpress se hacen posts en el blog. La empresa quiere hacer referencia a algún elemento o parte del mismo post con links, pero los elementos se sitúan en la parte superior de la web y son tapados por el menú fijo del sitio, en móviles y en desktop.

He pintado la línea roja para que vean donde llega el menú.
[image: Imagen 1]

Pero cuando se da clic en Sillas, por ejemplo, se mira así:
[image: Imagen 2]

Los elementos, a excepción del menú que lo hace el mismo Theme, se declaran así:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#sillas">Sillas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#teclado">Teclados</a></li>
    <li><a href="#mouse">Mouse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#mesa">Mesas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#auricularesaltavoces">Auriculares y Altavoces</a></li>
    <li><a href="#monitor">Monitores</a></li>
    <li><a href="#torres">Torres</a></li>
</ul>
<h4 id="sillas">Sillas</h4> // Línea que no funciona <=======
<a href="https://web.com/seccionDeSillas" target="_blank" rel="noopener" id="sillas"><img class="wp-image-21961 size-full aligncenter" src="https://web.com/sillas-gaming.jpg" alt="Equipamiento Gaming: Sillas" width="1640" height="424" /></a>
```

Primero les explico lo de `Línea que no funciona <=======`

Según el Theme y Rank Math, si se pone un **H4** y se oculta con CSS en las opciones del post, los link funcionan, pero al estar oculto el **H4** con `display: none;` no funciona para nada, así que decidí cambiarlos y poner el **id="sillas"** en el ancla que encierra a cada imagen. El resultado es la segunda imagen.

He probado ponerle a esa ancla el siguiente CSS, para ver si hago que baje, pero todo ha sido sin resultado positivo:

```
position: relative;
top: 100px; /* o cualquier numero */
margin-top: xxx;
padding-top: xxx;
```

Si hago visible el **H4** aunque no es lo ideal, pasa lo mismo, el **H4** se pega al top del sitio y es tapado por el menú. Se que debe haber una forma de bajar ese contenido o ponerlo justo debajo del menú pero se me han terminado las ideas.

Pueden darme alguna recomendación??